# Magento - Import hangs/freezes

Tags: magento, import

I'm currently trying to import a csv file of 940 products (1.57mb). When I use Magento v1.5.1.0 Import function (not the Dataflow function), it gives me the "Please wait..." screen and then hangs indefinitely. When I check the product catalog, all 940 products are there with SKU numbers, but that's it. No other product data seems to have been imported.

EDIT:
I was successfully able to import after dividing the file up into 3 parts of approximately 300 products. This leads me to believe that the csv file is fine, but the large amount of files is causing some sort of timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by increasing `max_execution_time` from 30 to 300 in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`